# Can contracts be passed between players by scooping?

Tags: elite-dangerous

Players can pass cargo like gold between their ships and that can then be traded.

Can players pass Powerplay contracts between ships by dumping/scooping? If so can those contracts then be used by the player who scoops them up?

Comment: If you're part of a different power that's allied to the same major faction, you undermine by stealing that cargo (without killing the ship). However, I don't know if you can use cargo that's for the same power in the way that you're asking...

Comment: I know about undermining, this would be more helping a friend get contracts faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No!**

Contracts are bound to the player who picked them up. Should you loose or jettison your cargo, you will either fail your contract or need to pick up identical cargo by any means available to you to complete the contract.

Basically, cargo is bound to a contract while the inverse does not hold.